# QTcpSocket Disconencted() Signal not emitted

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcpsocket, qtimer

**My code is seems to run fine !** **{(QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread: parent's thread:QThread(0x221f650), current thread:QThread(0x23a7950) : this error has been solved }**

**But**, when I unplug the LAN ,the **disconnected()** Signal is not emitted hence the **Reconenction timer** is not started and hence my code stops!
I tried to make my code in such a way that even if the connection is not available with the device,the ** Reconenction timer ** would be started after every **10 seconds** which on timeout and would be connected to slot **when_ReconnectionTimer_timeout()** try again and again until connected! But it seems the disconnected signal is not working!

```
#include "fduprocess.h"
#include<QDebug>
#include<QThread>
fduprocess::fduprocess(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
}

void fduprocess::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if(event->timerId()== _iStatusPollTimer)
    {
        if(_ClientSocketInstance.state() == QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState)
        {
            _ClientSocketInstance.write("alarmstat\r\n"); //25
            _ClientSocketInstance.write("selectedin\r\n"); // 4
            _ClientSocketInstance.write("sigoutstat\r\n"); //13
            _ClientSocketInstance.write("disablestat\r\n"); //5    
            _ClientSocketInstance.write("pwrstat\r\n"); //5    
            _ClientSocketInstance.write("siginstat\r\n");//5    
        }
    }
}

void fduprocess::tryit()
{
    qDebug()<< "...came inside tryit to tryit.........";
    connect(&_ReconnectionTimerInstance,SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(when_ReconnectionTimer_timeout()));
    qDebug()<<"process thread"<< QThread::currentThreadId();
    qDebug()<< "...conencted to whentimeout.........";
    connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_connected()));
    connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_disconnected()));
    connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_readyRead()));
    connect(&_ClientSocketInstance,SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(when_ClientSocketInstance_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    _strIPAddress = "192.168.1.135";
    _usiPort = 23;
    qDebug()<< "...end tryit........";
    _ReconnectionTimerInstance.setSingleShot(true);
    _ReconnectionTimerInstance.setInterval(10000);
    _ReconnectionTimerInstance.start();
    _iStatusPollTimer= startTimer(2000);    
}

void fduprocess::when_ReconnectionTimer_timeout()
{
    qDebug()<<"Reconnecting..";
    // qDebug()<< _ClientSocketInstance.children();
    _ClientSocketInstance.connectToHost(_strIPAddress, _usiPort);
    qDebug()<<"tryin gto reconect..";
}

void fduprocess::when_ClientSocketInstance_connected()
{ 
    qDebug()<<"Connected......";        
    _ClientSocketInstance.write("endrun_1");
    _ClientSocketInstance.flush();
    _ClientSocketInstance.write("\n");
    _ClientSocketInstance.write("\n");
    _ClientSocketInstance.write("\n");
    _ClientSocketInstance.flush();   
}

void fduprocess::when_ClientSocketInstance_disconnected()
{
    qDebug()<<"Disconnected";
    _ReconnectionTimerInstance.start();
}

void fduprocess::when_ClientSocketInstance_readyRead()
{
    QByteArray get = _ClientSocketInstance.readLine();
    qDebug() << "getting "<<get ;
}
```

**here is fduprocess.h**

```
#ifndef FDUPROCESS_H
#define FDUPROCESS_H
#include"fdu.h"
#include <QObject>
#include<QTimer>
#include<QTimerEvent>
#include<QTcpSocket>

class fduprocess : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString                 _strIPAddress;
    quint16                 _usiPort;
    public:
    explicit fduprocess(QObject *parent = 0);
    QTcpSocket              _ClientSocketInstance;
    QTimer               _ReconnectionTimerInstance ;
   int                     _iStatusPollTimer;
     void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
   signals:
   public slots:
    void tryit();
    void doOntimeout();
    void when_ReconnectionTimer_timeout();
    void when_ClientSocketInstance_connected();
    void when_ClientSocketInstance_disconnected();
    void when_ClientSocketInstance_readyRead();
    void when_ClientSocketInstance_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error);
};

#endif // FDUPROCESS_H
```

here is  **fdu.cpp**

```
#include "fdu.h"
#include "ui_fdu.h"
#include"fduprocess.h"
fdu::fdu(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::fdu)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QThread *workerThread =  new QThread;
    fduprocess *worker = new fduprocess;

 qDebug()<< "...goind to fduprocess........";

//    worker->_ReconnectionTimerInstance = setSingleShot(true);
//    worker->_ReconnectionTimerInstance.start(1000);
//    worker->_iStatusPollTimer = startTimer(500);
    worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
    worker->_ClientSocketInstance.moveToThread(workerThread);
    worker->_ReconnectionTimerInstance.moveToThread(workerThread);
    connect(workerThread,SIGNAL(started()),worker,SLOT(tryit()));
    connect(workerThread,SIGNAL(finished()),worker,SLOT(deleteLater()));
     workerThread->start();
    qDebug()<<"fdu thread "<<QThread::currentThreadId();

}

fdu::~fdu()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

and **main.cpp**

```
#include "fdu.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include<QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    fdu w;
    w.show();
  qDebug()<<"main thrad" <<QThread::currentThreadId();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Can anyone where I am making the mistake??

Please ignore my naming conventions and indentations,since I am in my learning curve

Comment: it is not duplicate.That issue is resolved! this issue is regarding signal.Please give some suggestion if possible

Comment: already fix it, I recommend you improve your question by providing a decent [mcve]

Comment: I got your point. I guess I made it as much minimally complete and verifiable as possible.

Comment: Your code is complete?, I think not because there are many things that are not defined, so it is not verifiable, it is minimal but the minimum is always the easiest to achieve since it is only remove code, so I recommend focus on improving the complete and verifiable to be a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry ! I have added the needed header. I hope it is fine now.

Comment: ok.thanx.I fixed

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! It seems I was confused with some concepts !
The state was Connecting so,it was not to be disconnected !

```
_ClientSocketInstance.disconnectFromHost();
    _ReconnectionTimerInstance.start();
```

**inside**  `when_ClientSocketInstance_error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError error)`

THIS would make that happen what I wanted.
Sorry for bugging all due to my confusing concepts.
Thanks for all your patience!